# Add a way to add URL setting to image slideshow Shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I am trying to add a link to one of the images in my slideshow. The below code shows my attempt, but I keep getting an error, I have followed the syntax. The error is in the attached image.

```
"blocks": [
{
  "type": "slider_image",
  "name": "Slider Image",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image",
      "label": "Image"
    },
{
"type": "url",
"id": "image_link",
"label": "Image Link"
},

  ]

}
],
```

[image]

Comment: Unhelpful error message! But at least there's extra commas that shouldn't be there. Try to find an online JSON validator or use an editor that points out errors in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the comma after the last block

[image]